# Obtaining an image from a server in my Android Program?

Tags: android

How do i access an image and display it in my android application from a server. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you getting any URL for image??

Comment: Yes i do have an url for the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to download image.

Make a function which will retrieve Bitmap.

This is shown here :[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new also on android development but I did that on one of my learning apps. If its a URL then you do the following:

```
              Drawable picture;
                      try {
                   URL picurl = new URL("some URL");
                   InputStream content = (InputStream)picurl.getContent();
                   picture = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                           //handle the Exception 
                       }
```